# -Xassembler and -Xpreprocessor examples

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, arm

I recently got my hands dirty with assembly and c code and found the gcc option -**Xassembler** -**Xpreprocessor**. i searched online for simple examples and the values these gcc options take, but couldn't find.

help appreciated.
thank you

Comment: Theses two options pass options to the assembler and preprocessor programs. `gcc` won't interpret the options passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**-Xassembler**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Assembler-Options.html): It passes an option to the assembler as a compilation option, such as specific options regarding architecture (which most probably GCC couldn't recognize). It is similar to **-Wa** (however the way to pass arguments change). For the completeness sake, I am used to see `-Wa` instead of `-Xassembler`, I guess backward compatibility explains why there are two similar options.

An example for -Xassembler (ARM arch): `-Xassembler -mthumb` to assemble for Thumb architectures (or `-Wa,-mthumb`).

[**-Xpreprocessor**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html): It passes an option to the preprocessor, as before, it is useful to pass options that GCC doesn't recognize. It is similar to **-Wp** (and the way to pass arguments change).

An example for -Xpreprocessor: `-Xpreprocessor -M` (or `-Wp,-M`) in order to

> output a rule suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file

Comment: i have gcc installed on my windows machine , but gcc -Xassembler -mthumb file.c doesn't work. it throws an errror saying **unknown option -- mthumb**

Comment: What's your target?

Comment: i have intel x86_64

Comment: -mthumb is only relevant for ARM CPUs.

Comment: I don't understand the Xpreprocessor example.  I thought it is used to pass (undocumented) options down to the preprocessor. But -M is documented and is a flag recognized by GCC.